# How to call a C++ dll file from Visual Basic 2010

Tags: c++, vb.net, visual-studio, dll

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express: the C++ and VB versions.

- There is some VB code that forms the body of a program, and all the GUI.
- There is also some C++ code that does some fast processing (lots of loops).

I am trying to call the C++ code, compiled as a dll, using:

> `Private Declare Sub CalcGraph Lib "Model.dll" ()`

And at the moment keep getting the error:

> Unhandled exception has occurred in your application.
>   Unable to find an entry point named 'CalcGraph' in DLL 'Model.dll'

Could someone explain how to correctly call the DLL, please? 
Do you need any other information to better understand the problem?

I'm fairly new to programming, so please be patient with me! 
That said, I'm prepared to do the leg-work, and have already spent quite a while reading around on this and other sites. Nothing seems to match quite well enough to help me understand what's going wrong.

Comment: Use Dumpbin.exe /exports on the DLL to see what the exported name looks like.  If probably isn't "CalcGraph".  Or is not exported.

Comment: @HansPassant Unfortunately dumpbin.exe doesn't seem to come with Visual Studio Express. I don't suppose that there's another tool that would do the job?

Comment: You are trying to hammer a nail with a screw driver.  Get the full version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, with your help and a fair bit of Google, this finally works!

Here's a run-down, in case it helps anyone else in the future:

- Use the [Ultimate Header File](http://www.flounder.com/ultimateheaderfile.htm) for a blueprint of how to create the header file.
- It is important to understand how compiling as C will not name mangle, whereas compiling as C++ will.
- It also appears that DevC++ has a neat `BUILDING_DLL` flag but Visual Studio requires you to create a definition in your main.c file.
- `__stdcall` does something called 'name decoration' that is different from name mangling but will still change your function name. Thanks to @slugonamission for giving me a pointer about this. It finally clicked when using dumpbin.exe, as suggested by @HansPassant.
- so, switching to `__cdecl` manages to avoid name decoration, and compiling in C (or using `extern` and compiling in C++) avoids name mangling.
- and the dll will finally give me CalcGraph as a valid entry point!

The Implicit / Explicit dll linking is a very important distinction. Implicit linking requires a .lib file, the .dll and perhaps also a .h file. Explicit linking is what I was after - you can get away with the .dll by itsself. Thanks to @squelos for the link explaining this.

And last but not least:

In the dll:

```
extern _COMPILING_ void __cdecl CalcGraph(PanelParameters *, Calculations *);
```

And in the VB code:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Private Declare Sub CalcGraph Lib "myDLL.dll" (ByRef params As Parameters, _
ByRef calcs As Calculations)
```

And it finally worked!

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume here the C++ DLL is written in pure C++ (not C++/CLI or anything like that). It seems that the VB `Lib` keyword will only be importing a .NET procedure, rather than a native procedure. Instead, you need to use [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719104%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Something like this may work

```
<DllImport("Model.dll")>
Public Shared Function CalcGraph
End Function
```

But of course, fill in your parameters and return types too.

Comment: Aha, that looks promising. Unfortunately I still can't fix the "can't find the entry point" error. Might the format of my C++ code be causing problems? The C++ looks like this `DLLIMPORT void __stdcall CalcGraph(Parameters *params, Calculations *calcs)` . A look around the web also suggests that [something has happened to P/Invoke](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?p=3886197&referrerid=61394) between VS2008 and VS2010 which might also be causing problems. Please let me know if you have any other suggestions. I'll keep tinkering in the meantime...

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure. It could be the `__stdcall` (as it mangles names differently). Since it's C++, you may also need `extern "C"` too.

Comment: GnomeDePlume, well I quite often use p/invoke from a C# solution (framework 4.0) in VS 2010, and I havent encountered many problems while P/Invoking. Having said that, I only have very little experience with VS2008. But I cant really see what could have changed between both versions.

Comment: @squelos Is sounds as though the [default settings changed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff361650%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), and that it can cause some problems with mangled code. But I'm not very experienced at this ... everything looks like a problem from down here!  It is good to hear that your experiences have been more positive.

Comment: Yeah, well me too at the start, it was some real mess. Then I said : ok im gonna stop trying to guess how to use Dlls, and read some doc about DLL's, so now, it just makes things a lot easier. People seem to forget that a .dll is just an extension. They can be made in a few different ways, and used in a lot of different ways :)

But then im not saying you are not still going to encounter syntax/param errors while doing so.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, depending on how the DLL was generated (ordinal or by name) you may have to use the DLL with [GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64tkc9y5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

This documentation here can give you a quick overview of how to use DLL's the oldschool way [MSDN Linking overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/253b8k2c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

And finally, [DumpBin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) can you help you out  a lot, by allowing you to inspect a DLL (pretty useful if you dont have the sources or documentation )