# Call a VB Program from a C++ dll

Tags: c++, vba, dll

I am using a software which gives me flexibility to customize using C++ dll. I have written my own dll program which is running fine. I have also created a GUI designed in VB which I want to run from the C++ dll itself. The C++ dll needs to call the VB GUI and should also be able to send parameters (mostly string type) to the VB program. How do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

I think, the technology you are looking for is the MFC automation.
Take a look at this document, please: http://www.tenouk.com/download/pdf/visualcplusmfc24.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You could take the automation (COM) approach, or you could just call the dll from the GUI directly (the dll calling the GUI might cause headaches). 
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632713/how-to-call-a-c-dll-file-from-visual-basic-2010) talks about calling a dll in VB. You'll need to read about P/invoke.

There are more details [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/106553) - note that if you use a C++ interface you will get name mangling. It is sometimes simpler to make the "interface" pure C.