# Why is copy constructor faster than Me.Copy()?

Tags: vb.net

Given below two methods, why is copy constructor slower by about 100ms in DEBUG mode?

I converted a bunch of deep Copy() methods to corresponding copy ctor()s in a real project and found that copy ctor()s are performing worse than earlier deep Copy() methods.

I've checked the IL and they seem seem very similar to me.

```
Public Sub New(ByVal pClass1 As Foo)
    A = pClass1.A
    B = pClass1.B
    C = pClass1.C
    D = pClass1.D
    E = pClass1.E
    F = pClass1.F
    G = pClass1.G
    H = pClass1.H
    I = pClass1.I
    J = pClass1.J
    K = pClass1.K
    L = pClass1.L
    M = pClass1.M
    N = pClass1.N
    O = pClass1.O
    P = pClass1.P
    Q = pClass1.Q
    R = pClass1.R
    S = pClass1.S
    T = pClass1.T
    U = pClass1.U
    V = pClass1.V
    W = pClass1.W
    X = pClass1.X
    Y = pClass1.Y
    Z = pClass1.Z

    TheOther = If(pClass1.TheOther Is Nothing, Nothing, New Foo(pClass1.TheOther))
End Sub

Public Function Copy() As Foo
    Dim obj As Foo = New Foo()

    obj.A = A
    obj.B = B
    obj.C = C
    obj.D = D
    obj.E = E
    obj.F = F
    obj.G = G
    obj.H = H
    obj.I = I
    obj.J = J
    obj.K = K
    obj.L = L
    obj.M = M
    obj.N = N
    obj.O = O
    obj.P = P
    obj.Q = Q
    obj.R = R
    obj.S = S
    obj.T = T
    obj.U = U
    obj.V = V
    obj.W = W
    obj.X = X
    obj.Y = Y
    obj.Z = Z

    obj.TheOther = If(TheOther Is Nothing, Nothing, TheOther.Copy())

    Return obj
End Function
```

I'm using a Stopwatch to measure performance of each way of creating a new copy object 10,000,000 times. Copy ctor() always comes about 100 ms slower than Me.Copy().

This is quite puzzling; can someone shed some light on this? Note: I've read about ICloneable, IDeepCloneable etc. But, for this project, I'm convinced consistent copy ctor() is they way to go; so, please avoid repeating these suggestions. I'm just interested in learning why copy ctor() would perform slower.

Comment: Perhaps because the constructor of a class has some overhead not present in a simple method? 100ms is the difference for a single iteration or for the whole iteration loop?

Comment: Why measure in Debug mode?

Comment: In my [test](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dN60Wa) copy constructor is faster than the copy function, could you please provide more details on how you are testing in your question? Thanks

Comment: @Steve 100 ms for the full 10 million iterations. This is not much for this simplified example but the difference is significant in the real world application.

Comment: @Christos Here is my [example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TgK00y). .NET fiddler is coming up with **`Copy Constructor took: 4,524ms Copy function took: 4,531ms`** but in VS2017 **`Copy ctor took 1428 Copy() took 1380`** in DEBUG mode and **`Copy ctor took 139 Copy() took 139`** in RELEASE mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment and tests you can see that you can only assume that the copy constructor is slower only in VS debug mode. So your question cannot be answered per se, however it is worth to mention that there is a difference between release and debug modes in visual studio take a look [here](https://vinayakgarg.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/difference-between-debug-build-and-release-build/) for example. The most important difference is the optimization that takes place in the final binary in release mode.

Considering the "general" use of VB.NET which isn't the performance rather than the rapid application development (R.A.D.) I don't think that doing a deep research in the debug mode insights, in order to discover what really happens, would be helpful in this particular issue or in most similar ones.

So I suggest to go with the copy constructor not only because our tests show that it is actually faster but most important (in my opinion) because, as a technique, is clearer and more "tidy" than the copy function.

After all if performance in those kind of operations is a significant factor in your application and some standard functions like [MemberwiseClone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.memberwiseclone?view=netframework-4.7.2) doesn't fit your needs then you should separate your object libraries and use C++ to create the required object manipulation operations. I am not an expert in this field but I have seen this technique in various places like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632713/how-to-call-a-c-dll-file-from-visual-basic-2010).

I know that this isn't answer your question exactly and it is mostly opinion based but I think that as VB.NET developers we shouldn't be bothered too much with the performance of very specific operations rather than the overall performance of the application. For example a 3 minutes lasting reporting operation won't be any better if we take it down to 2 minutes and 45 seconds (if you know what I mean).

Hope this helps.